# Install PIL1.1.7 for Python 27 on 64bit Windows 7 - Wrong Directory Selected

Tags: python, python-2.7, panda3d

I need to install PIL 1.1.7, particularly the Image and ImageTk modules, for writing Tkinter GUI codes with Python 2.7.

When I initiated the installation, although Python 2.7 was detected in the registry, the Python and Installation Directory selected was not Python 2.7 but Panda3D-1.8.1\python. I know PIL is applicable for Panda3D as well but that's not my goal.

As far as I can tell, I cannot change the directories.

I think uninstalling Panda3D then install PIL may be an option but more of a last-resort option.

Any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you _really_ need to install PIL 1.1.7 instead of [Pillow 2.3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/)?

Comment: If you must stick with PIL 1.1.7 for some reason, IIRC the only place to find help on this is late-2009/early-2010 postings in the [Image-SIG](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/) archives, because neither the original buggy 1.1.7 installers nor the docs were ever updated after the 2009 release. [Christoph Gohkle's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow) had fixed installers for a while, but he's since switched to providing Pillow for everything but Python 2.5.

Comment: Thanks. I will try downloading Pillow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/General_Preparation#borderleft):

> What if I already have a copy of Python?
>
> If you already have a copy of python, and you wish to use that instead
>   of the one provided with panda, it is easy to do so.
>
> Simply create a "panda.pth" file inside your copy of python,
>   containing the path of the panda directory and the bin directory
>   within it on separate lines (for example C:\Program
>   Files\Panda3D-1.2.3 and C:\Program Files\Panda3D-1.2.3\bin).
>
> This will enable your copy of python to find the panda libraries.
>        For this to work, the version of python that you use must match the version of python included with panda.
>
> The panda libraries are compiled for that particular version, and will
>   not work with any other.
>        Of course, if you do use your own copy of python, you may wish to delete panda's copy of python, or at least, remove it from the PATH
>   environment variable.   Otherwise, you will have two copies of python,
>   which can lead to confusion.

Follow above instructions, and at the end after you remove path of  panda's copy of python from `PATH`, add the path of current python to `PATH`, and then install `PIL` or `Pillow` again, now it should find your current python.